# Android Game development E/JavaBinder: FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-play-games, game-loop

How to deal with E/JavaBinder: FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION that crashes the app?

I am making an android game using a SurfaceView.

I am also using a dedicated thread for the infinite Game-Loop itself, which contains both an update() method, as well as a draw() method.

The update() method updates characters position(logic) and sprites, while the draw() method draws to the canvas.

The dedicated thread handles both  update() and draw() since they need to be synchronized.

The onTouchEvents (user clicks) are handled by the main thread.

Although I cannot tell for sure, I suspect that I am getting this error: **E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!** , because
both the draw() method and the update() method call other methods that call other methods and so on.. resulting in an almost a recursive behavior.

For example my update() method, calls characterOne.update().. which then calls characterOneSpells.update() which then calls spellOne.update() and so on... same thing for the draw().  I suspect that this overflows the bind buffer or something like that.. I am not sure.. and all of this is happening in an infinite loop infinite amount of times.

Note that I took this approach ( methods call methods that call other methods) because logically it made sense to me that a character should be responsible to draw **itself**, and a spell should be responsible to draw **itself**, **rather than the character be responsible to draw and update the spells and so on.** It made sense to me that every object should be responsible to draw itself and update itself, and that is my reasoning, I might be wrong, please let me know what you think.

Now, I am new to game making, and in fact this is my first game, so please take it easy on me, I am trying to learn!

Sample of my code and the error log can be found below.

Any insight to why I am getting this **E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!** and how to fix it would be very much appreciated! Also feel free to suggest a better design or approach, since I am trying to learn.

Thank you!

I marked the important parts of the code with ** Important ** comment to make things easier.`

**ERROR LOG:**

```
    11-17 17:07:30.132 934-1460/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
11-17 17:07:30.388 1451-1451/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
11-17 17:07:32.328 934-992/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '329e61e3 com.amazon.firelauncher/com.amazon.firelauncher.Launcher (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-17 17:07:32.407 146-146/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/2493/oom_score_adj; errno=2
11-17 17:07:32.442 934-1011/? E/WifiService: Multicaster binderDied
11-17 17:07:32.462 146-146/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/2493/oom_score_adj; errno=2
11-17 17:07:32.464 146-146/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/2493/oom_score_adj; errno=2
11-17 17:07:32.464 146-146/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/1217/oom_score_adj; errno=2
11-17 17:07:36.426 6868-6868/? E/cr_AWVDeploymentClient: Chromium Version = v59 key doesn't exist. So, default version config will be used.
11-17 17:07:36.428 6868-6868/? E/cr_AWVDeploymentClient: Default device config doesn't exist
11-17 17:07:39.313 934-992/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '11e88fc0 info.evyatar.mystrategygame/info.evyatar.mystrategygame.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-17 17:07:40.905 7010-7051/? E/SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 44 frames from WAL file /data/user/0/com.amazon.firelauncher/databases/producer.db-wal
11-17 17:07:41.091 7010-7059/? E/SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 90 frames from WAL file /data/user/0/com.amazon.firelauncher/databases/CardDeviceAgentDB-wal
11-17 17:07:43.558 7010-7010/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
11-17 17:07:43.622 7089-7089/? E/TimeoutManagerClient: bindService() Failed to bind to ECService
11-17 17:07:43.631 7165-7165/? E/Dagger2: ApplicationModule context already set
11-17 17:07:44.924 7089-7311/? E/...iceDataCommunication: Got a RemoteMAPException
                                                          com.amazon.identity.auth.device.framework.RemoteMAPException: com.amazon.identity.auth.device.api.DeviceDataStoreException: Key ke_device was not found in the device data store. This device does not support ke_device. This error is expected if the device not support ke_device.
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.framework.SecureContentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(SecureContentResolver.java:118)
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataCommunication.retriveValueFromCentralStore(DeviceDataCommunication.java:59)
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataCommunication.getValue(DeviceDataCommunication.java:52)
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataStoreSystemPropertyDecorator.getValue(DeviceDataStoreSystemPropertyDecorator.java:52)
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.api.DeviceDataStore.getValue(DeviceDataStore.java:96)
                                                              at com.amazon.avod.identity.DeviceProperties.isKidsEditionDevice(DeviceProperties.java:374)
                                                              at com.amazon.avod.identity.DeviceProperties.initialize(DeviceProperties.java:201)
                                                              at com.amazon.avod.core.ApplicationComponents$InitializeDeviceProperties.initialize(ApplicationComponents.java:543)
                                                              at com.amazon.avod.core.ApplicationComponents$InitializeRunnable.run(ApplicationComponents.java:787)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                           Caused by: com.amazon.identity.auth.device.api.DeviceDataStoreException: Key ke_device was not found in the device data store. This device does not support ke_device. This error is expected if the device not support ke_device.
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataCommunication$1.useContentProviderClient(DeviceDataCommunication.java:93)
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataCommunication$1.useContentProviderClient(DeviceDataCommunication.java:61)
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.framework.SecureContentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(SecureContentResolver.java:112)
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataCommunication.retriveValueFromCentralStore(DeviceDataCommunication.java:59) 
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataCommunication.getValue(DeviceDataCommunication.java:52) 
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataStoreSystemPropertyDecorator.getValue(DeviceDataStoreSystemPropertyDecorator.java:52) 
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.api.DeviceDataStore.getValue(DeviceDataStore.java:96) 
                                                              at com.amazon.avod.identity.DeviceProperties.isKidsEditionDevice(DeviceProperties.java:374) 
                                                              at com.amazon.avod.identity.DeviceProperties.initialize(DeviceProperties.java:201) 
                                                              at com.amazon.avod.core.ApplicationComponents$InitializeDeviceProperties.initialize(ApplicationComponents.java:543) 
                                                              at com.amazon.avod.core.ApplicationComponents$InitializeRunnable.run(ApplicationComponents.java:787) 
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
11-17 17:07:45.701 7010-7085/? E/...iceDataCommunication: Got a RemoteMAPException
                                                          com.amazon.identity.auth.device.framework.RemoteMAPException: com.amazon.identity.auth.device.api.DeviceDataStoreException: Key re_device was not found in the device data store. This device does not support re_device. This error is expected if the device not support re_device.
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.framework.SecureContentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(SecureContentResolver.java:118)
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataCommunication.retriveValueFromCentralStore(DeviceDataCommunication.java:59)
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataCommunication.getValue(DeviceDataCommunication.java:52
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                           Caused by: com.amazon.identity.auth.device.api.DeviceDataStoreException: Key re_device was not found in the device data store. This device does not support re_device. This error is expected if the device not support re_device.
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataCommunication$1.useContentProviderClient(DeviceDataCommunication.java:93)
                                                              at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.devicedata.DeviceDataCommunication$1.useContentProviderClient(DeviceDataCommunication.java:61)

                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.services.MapCache.updateDeviceData(MapCache.java:579) 
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.services.MapCache.access$700(MapCache.java:47) 
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.services.MapCache$3.run(MapCache.java:491) 
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.services.BackgroundExecutor$InternalRunnable.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:180) 
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
11-17 17:07:45.930 7343-7343/? E/SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 120 frames from WAL file /data/securedStorageLocation/com.amazon.providers.contentsupport/contentsupport.db-wal
11-17 17:07:45.979 7343-7343/? E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on languages(packageId)
11-17 17:07:46.007 7343-7343/? E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on languages(packageId)
11-17 17:07:47.386 7010-7417/? E/F_C.ArcusRemoteConfigur: No valid offline remote setting found for the current device, not setting default
                                                          java.lang.Exception: Error getting the baseline setting for Arcus config cms
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.settings.OfflineSetting.value(OfflineSetting.java:106)

                                                              at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                           Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Exception reading from cms/baseline.json
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.settings.JSONFile.value(JSONFile.java:43)
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.settings.JSONFile.value(JSONFile.java:14)
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.settings.OfflineSetting.value(OfflineSetting.java:88)
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.settings.OfflineSetting.value(OfflineSetting.java:22) 
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.arcus.ArcusRemoteConfiguration$1.map(ArcusRemoteConfiguration.java:67) 
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.arcus.ArcusRemoteConfiguration$1.map(ArcusRemoteConfiguration.java:60) 
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.arcus.ArcusRemoteConfiguration.initialize(ArcusRemoteConfiguration.java:117) 
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.cards.RecommendationsController.getInstance(RecommendationsController.java:111) 
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.ProducerService.onHandleIntent(ProducerService.java:57) 
                                                              at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                           Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cms/baseline.json
                                                              at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
                                                              at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
                                                              at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.settings.JSONFile.value(JSONFile.java:29)
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.settings.JSONFile.value(JSONFile.java:14) 
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.settings.OfflineSetting.value(OfflineSetting.java:88) 

                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.cards.RecommendationsController.getInstance(RecommendationsController.java:111) 
                                                              at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.ProducerService.onHandleIntent(ProducerService.java:57) 
                                                              at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
11-17 17:07:47.400 7010-7417/? E/F_C.FireDeviceAttribute: BuildNumber is not a valid String attribute (wrong type: Integer)
11-17 17:07:47.416 7010-7417/? E/F_C.ArcusParameters: Exception getting attribute %s, no attribute added
                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: attrValue cannot be null
                                                          at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.remoteconfiguration.internal.gear.Checks.checkNotNull(Checks.java:20)
                                                          at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.remoteconfiguration.internal.AttributesImpl.addAttributePrivate(AttributesImpl.java:193)
                                                          at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.remoteconfiguration.internal.AttributesImpl.addAttribute(AttributesImpl.java:103)
                                                          at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.arcus.ArcusParameters.decorateManager(ArcusParameters.java:87)
                                                          at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.arcus.ArcusRemoteConfiguration.initialize(ArcusRemoteConfiguration.java:119)
                                                          at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.cards.RecommendationsController.getInstance(RecommendationsController.java:111)
                                                          at com.amazon.firelauncher.reccardproducer.ProducerService.onHandleIntent(ProducerService.java:57)
                                                          at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

**Sample Code**

```
        public class GameLoop extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Context myContext;
    private SurfaceHolder mySurfaceHolder;
    private Bitmap backgroundImg;
    private int screenW = 1;
    private int screenH = 1;
    private boolean running = false;
    private boolean onTitleScreen = true;
    private GameLoopThread thread;
    private int backgroundOrigW;
    private int backgroundOrigH;
    private float scaleW;
    private float scaleH;
    private float drawScaleW;
    private float drawScaleH;
    private int fingerX, fingerY;
    private boolean isDragging = false;
    SingltonAssetsObject mSingltonAssetsObject;
    private boolean gameOver;
    Point userClickPoint;

    //Characters
    CharacterTypeOne characterFighterOne,characterFighterTwo,characterFighterThree;
    CharacterTypeTwo CharacterMage;

    public GameLoop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        //init clickRectangle
        userClickPoint = new Point();

        //creates the gameLoop thread DRAW THREAD
        thread = new GameLoopThread(holder,context);
        setFocusable(true);


    }


    public void initCharacters(){
        mSingltonAssetsObject = SingltonAssetsObject.getInstance(myContext,scaleW,scaleH);

        characterFighterOne = new characterFighterOne(myContext,1000,1,150,350,100,15,1.0,scaleW,scaleH,drawScaleW,drawScaleH,screenW,screenH);
        characterFighterTwo = new characterFighterOne(myContext,1001,67,350,350,100,15,1.0,scaleW,scaleH,drawScaleW,drawScaleH,screenW,screenH);
        characterFighterThree =  new characterFighterOne(myContext,1002,99,550,350,1000,15,1.0,scaleW,scaleH,drawScaleW,drawScaleH,screenW,screenH);

        characterMage = new characterMage(myContext,50,28,650,250,100,15,0.1,scaleW,scaleH,drawScaleW,drawScaleH,screenW,screenH);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return thread.doTouchEvent(event);
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        thread.setSurfaceSize(width, height);
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread.setRunning(true);
        if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
            thread.start();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread.setRunning(false);
    }


    class GameLoopThread extends Thread{

        public GameLoopThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context){
            //initialzied in inner class and not outter because this variable will act as a lock and will be shard with all threads
            mySurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            myContext = context;
            //the background image of the title screen
            backgroundImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.title);
            backgroundOrigW = backgroundImg.getWidth();
            backgroundOrigH = backgroundImg.getHeight();
        }
        //This method is the main game loop
        public  void run() {

            while (running) {

                    try { //lock canvas for drawing
                        c = mySurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                        synchronized (mySurfaceHolder) {
                            if (!gameOver)
                            {    
                                //** important ***
                                updateAnimationsAndPosition();
                            }

                            // **important **
                            draw(c);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (c != null) { //unlock canvas
                            mySurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        }
                    }
                } //while loop ends            
        } //run Method ends (gameLOOP)


        //This method will draw everything to the screen
        public void draw(Canvas canvas){
                canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImg, 0, 0, null);
                if (!onTitleScreen) {
                          /* **Important**
                          Note: characterFighterOne.draw(canvas) calls spells.draw(canvas) 
                          which calls spellOne.draw(canvas).. which call spellIndicartor.draw(canvas) 
                          and so on... might be cauing the isssue?*/
                         characterFighterOne.draw(canvas);
                         characterFighterTwo.draw(canvas);
                         characterFighterThree.draw(canvas);
                         characterMage.draw(canvas);
                }
        }

        //This method updates the animations, for example changes image  every tick
        public void updateAnimationsAndPosition(){

            if(!onTitleScreen){
             /***Important**
                Note: characterFighterOne.updateAnimationsAndPosition() calls spells.update() 
                which calls spellOne.update().. which call spellIndicartor.update() 
                and so on... might be causing the issue?*/

                characterFighterOne.updateAnimationsAndPosition();  
                characterFighterTwo.updateAnimationsAndPosition();
                characterFighterThree.updateAnimationsAndPosition();
                characterMage.updateAnimationsAndPosition();
            }
        }

        public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
            synchronized (mySurfaceHolder) {
                screenW = width;
                screenH = height;
                backgroundImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backgroundImg, width, height, true);
                drawScaleW = (float) screenW / 960; //screen/background width image
                drawScaleH = (float) screenH / 640;


            }
        }
        //This method is in charge of user input ( clicks on screen, and how to respond to them)
        public boolean doTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
            if(!onTitleScreen){
                characterFighterOne.doTouchEvent(event);
                characterFighterTwo.doTouchEvent(event);
                characterFighterThree.doTouchEvent(event);
                characterMage.doTouchEvent(event);
                userClickPoint.set((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
            }
            synchronized (mySurfaceHolder) {
                int eventaction = event.getAction();
                int X = (int)event.getX();
                int Y = (int)event.getY();

                switch (eventaction ) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if(!gameOver){
                            fingerX = X;
                            fingerY = Y;
                            if (!onTitleScreen) {

                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:// used for dragging purposes
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //Here I load all the images to memory ( while on the titleScreen normal size & scaled, find a better place, maybe OnCreate, leave for now)
                        if (onTitleScreen) {
                            backgroundImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), R.drawable.background);
                            backgroundImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backgroundImg, screenW, screenH, true);
                            onTitleScreen = false;
                            scaleW = (float) screenW/ (float) backgroundOrigW;
                            scaleH = (float) screenH/ (float) backgroundOrigH;
                            initCharacters();
                        }
                        if (gameOver) {
                            gameOver = false;
                        }
                        break;
                } 
            } 
            return true;
        } 

        //This method enables and disables the Thread
        public void setRunning(boolean b) {
        running = b;
    }


    } 

}
```